# Simple code needs to convert into loop from recursive function

Tags: loops

Can anybody convert this from recursion into iteration?

```
BEGIN SEQ(n)
  IF (n EQUALS 1) THEN
    RETURN 3
  ELSEIF (n EQUALS 2) THEN
    RETURN 2
  ELSE
    RETURN SEQ(n – 2) + SEQ(n – 1)
  ENDIF
END
```

Comment: What programming language is this? Please tag your question with the language in use. To update your question, click on the **"[edit]"** link under the post. Thank you.

Comment: We would rather not have do-it-for-me-urgently questions here (downvoted, voted to close). Please mark this with the language you are using, make a decent effort yourself, and do not mark any of your questions as urgent - that is not how to address volunteers. It really isn't urgent for us at all.

Answer (score 0):

These are the Fibonaccis starting with 3,2, then going 5, 7 etc.
So you could set it up where if you are passed n, if n is 1 or 2 you make a special case, and otherwise you say something like:
a=3
b=2
for (I am leaving it for you figure out the indices)
{temp=b; b=b+a;a=temp}
return b

I do not want to say more since this seems to be a homework problem and answers are not supposed to do all of the work.

Comment: Or if you want only n equals one could be a special case. If n is two, your for loop could run zero times, I think, and the rest would make sense.